# How to update magento stock directly in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, magento-1.9

I'm writing C# program, to update my magento store using feed files from suppliers. So far it works very well, but when quantity = "0", on storefront, product is still shown as available, only when trying to buy it, says it's not available.
My question is, how set it to out of stock, when quantity = "0".
Here is my C# code:

```
    public void updateHB(string sku, string qty, string price)
    {
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand(
                //update qty
                "update cataloginventory_stock_item set qty = '" + qty + "' " +
                "where cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id = " +
                "(select catalog_product_entity.entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku ='" + sku + "');" +

                //update price, stock price + 15%
                "update catalog_product_entity_decimal set value = (" + price + " * 1.15) " +
                "where catalog_product_entity_decimal.attribute_id = '75' and " +
                "catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id = " +
                "(select catalog_product_entity.entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku ='" + sku + "');"
                , connect);
            query.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
            successMSG(sku);
        }
        catch
        {
            errorMSG();
        }
    }
```

In database table "cataloginventory_stock_item" i can see column "is_in_stock", changing value to "0" doesn't make it "Out Of Stock" on storefront.
How Magento sets products to "Out Of Stock"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, may be helpful for some one else as well.

```
                //set available in stock = 1; out of stock = 0;
                "update cataloginventory_stock_status set stock_status = '1' " +
                "where cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id = " +
                "(select catalog_product_entity.entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku ='" + sku + "');"
```